# PHP MySQL Warning: Illegal string offset 'title'

Tags: php, mysql, string

I get this error:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\wamp64\www\Beep\php\config.php on line 33

When using this function:

```
function getComments() {
global $pdo;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `comments`";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetch();

$comments = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    array_push($comments, new Comment($result["title"], $result["content"], $result["author"]));
}
return $comments;}

class Comment {

    var $title;
    var $content;
    var $author;

    /**
     * Comment constructor.
     * @param $title
     * @param $content
     * @param $author
     */
    public function __construct($title, $content, $author){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->author = $author;
    }
}
```

Line 33 is

```
array_push($comments, new Comment($result["title"], $result["content"], $result["author"]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fetch()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns a single record. When you `foreach()` over the result, you iterator the values of the row, not rows.

Use [`fetchAll()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get all records.

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['title'];
}
```

In your initial code :

```
$results = $stmt->fetch();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result; // here $result is id, then title, and so on.
}
```